# Unresolved external symbol - Static

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

I'm trying to recreate a game (copy of Pong), using a [tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Game-From-Scratch-CPP-Edition-Part-4.aspx) (I'm learning SFML atm). After I got the menu and the SplashScreen working, I started to implement the player, when I get the error
 `'LNK2001 - unresolved external symbol "private: static class PlayerPaddle Game::_player1" (?_player1@Game@@0VPlayerPaddle@@A)'`. 

I tried everything came to my mind, i searched on Google, asked some friends, and I still can't get it done. Here is the whole code: https://github.com/AlinP25/Pang-Tut . What is the problem and how can I solve it? I'm desperate. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to instantiate `_player1` in `Game.cpp`. Do it at the end next to `_mainWindow` and `_gameState`:

```
PlayerPaddle Game::_player1;
```

Comment: You just saved me. Thanks a lot :)